# Datepicker onchangemonthyear beforeshowday

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the datepicker on a modal of twitter bootstrap. 
in order to highlight some dates, the datepicker is generated in the 'success'-part as an ajax-call.

I manage to highlight the dates I want to highlight in the current month, which is fine.

But when I toggle to the previous or next month, I would like to make that ajax-call again and render dates to highlight. Below you can see my code:

```
function nonValidated() {           

        var date = new Date();
        date.addDays(-date.getDate() + 1);
        var startDate = [date.getDate().lpad(2), (date.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2), date.getFullYear()].join('/');
        var enddate = new Date();
        enddate.setDate(date.getDaysInMonth());
        var endDate = [enddate.getDate().lpad(2), (enddate.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2), enddate.getFullYear()].join('/');
        var depId = $('#serviceSelector').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ServiceManagement/GetUnassignedSlots",
            data: { "from": startDate, "to": endDate, "depId": depId },
            success: function (data) {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults(
                  $.extend(
                    { 'dateFormat': 'dd/mm/yy' },
                    $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE']
                  )
                );
                $("#nonValidatedDatepicker").datepicker(
                    {
                        inline: true,
                        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

                            var theday = date.getDate() + '/' +
                            (date.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2) + '/' +
                            date.getFullYear();
                            return [true, $.inArray(theday, data.result) >= 0 ? "warningDate" : ''];
                        },
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            var dateParts = dateText.split('/');
                            if (dateParts[0][0] == '0') dateParts[0] = dateParts[0][1];
                            if (dateParts[1][0] == '0') dateParts[1] = dateParts[1][1];
                            var newdate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[0]-1, dateParts[1]);

                            var dayOfWeek = newdate.getDay();
                            if (dayOfWeek == 0) dayOfWeek = 7;
                            var weekstart = new Date(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), newdate.getDate());
                            weekstart.addDays(-dayOfWeek + 1);
                            var weekend = new Date(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), newdate.getDate());
                            weekend.addDays(7 - dayOfWeek);

                            $('#SelectWeekDate').val([weekstart.getDate().lpad(2), (weekstart.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2), weekstart.getFullYear()].join('/') + ' - ' + [weekend.getDate().lpad(2), (weekend.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2), weekend.getFullYear()].join('/'));
                            $('#modalNonValidated').modal('hide');
                            InitFillPage();
                        },
                        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, widget) {


                        }
                    }
                    );

            },
            error: function (data) {
            },
            statusCode: {
                401: function (data) {
                    //ERROR 401: Unauthenticated
                    window.location.href = '/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

anyone an idea how I can combine onchangemonthyear and beforeshowday?

Answer (score 2):

I would split the code that shows the datepicker and the code that makes the ajax call to get the data for the datepicker (the data that determines which days to highlight) into 2 separate functions. You can call the function that makes the ajax call from the function that first shows the datepicker, and again from your onChangeMonthYear function.  Also, make sure that the ajax call to get the data is made *synchronously* (set async: false option) so that the data comes back before your beforeShowDay function runs.

Hope that helps!